# Can I setup openx api ( opensource ads service ) in windows 7 through xampp 1.6.8

Tags: openx

I wanna use Openx with api on windows 7 through xampp 1.6.8 . Can't find tutorial for setup and use openx api on windows.

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need to install a XML-RPC2 client library and then use it to access the remote OpenX server API.

Do you have access to the OpenX server? If so, and if you prefer to use REST, then you can install this REST API in the server (developed by me):

http://openxrest.com